# R package random forest: can corr.bias be harmful?

Tags: random-forest, bias

There exists an option corr.bias for making regression analyses with the R package randomForest. The manual warns “Experimental. Use at your own risk.” What does corr.bias precisely do and why can it be dangerous to use it? As far as I know the bias correction is based on a linear regression between the out-of-bag-prediction and the observed values which is used for correction of all predictions made by the model, but this does not appear so harmful to me.

Comment: Usually something is designated experimental when it has not undergone rigorous testing. Think of it as being in an mature alpha, or a beta release. (To refer to terms used in a software release life cycle) If you can/or want check the source code for comments or notes, it might be helpful also.

Comment: I have tested it a bit and it either performs a little better or a little worse. I have never seen the "great improvement" they talk about. How does it work anyway? can anyone point me to some references? I have yet to find a description of how it is performed.